# Using a button click as a keyboard entry in a Winforms project - SendKeys not working

Tags: c#, keyboard

I have a Winforms app and want to add my own buttons for a number keypad:

[image]

The empty table is a ObjectListView table. The cells in columns "Tool Location" and "Template Location" are editable. I also want the key buttons to add numbers to the "Search by tool number" TextBox as well.

I have tried the following when a button is clicked. It seems to do nothing:

```
    private void NumberButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        SendKeys.Send(b.Text);
    }
```

I want my botton click to go to the default editor. How?

Answer (score 0):

let's say your tool-number-Textbox is called `tb_toolNumber`

```
private void NumberButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    tb_toolNumber.Text += b.Text;
}
```

should work (assuming I got your question right)

Comment: That is what I do not want to do. I want to edit the value of the cell currently selected (blue in the graphic) or the TextBox. What you suggest is where I started. If I do what you propose then it always edits just the tb_toolNumber.Text and never the cells in the list.

Comment: " I also want the key buttons to add numbers to the "Search by tool number" TextBox as well." That's what you wrote....

Comment: don't know what control (not using winforms for a while) you have for `Tool Location & Co.`, but if it's a Datagrid, maybe you can catch the event of entering the cell, save the cell as variable and put text there...?